# Generate word document from trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Is there a way for me to format the word document during generation?

```
contentversion.pathonclient = 'test.doc'
contentversion.versiondata = blob.typeof('ids of the object +'&nbsp'+'Name of the records'+<br>);
insert contentversion;
```

The above code creates a word document. However, the html tags are not being applied.
What is the best approach to implement this?

Comment: This code is not syntactically valid, and does not generate a Word document. If you generate HTML and lie to Word that it is a `.doc` file, you're at the mercy of what Word's rendering engine decides to do with it.

Comment: Thank you, but in what other way can I generate a .doc file from trigger?

Comment: this should be of help -- [turn a VF page into a word doc](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000314591&mode=1&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null&type=1)

Comment: @cropredy I'm trying to generate it from a trigger and not from VF page.

Answer (score 1):

We can also invoke the vf page from the apex, that will get the complete vf page as word document as blob and you can insert content version with that blob

This is how it will look like

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="ControllerName" contentType="application/msword#filename.doc" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false"
applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false">

    <html>
        <body>      
        </body>
    </html>
</page>
```

Controller/Trigger:

```
PageReference pageOutput = new PageReference('/apex/MyVfPage');
//Pass params to vf if required 
Blob setBody = pageOutput.getContentAsPdf();

//ContentVersion Instance
contentVersionInstance.VersionData = setBody;
contentVersionInstance.PathOnClient = 'MyFile.doc';

//dml
```

But you have to be careful while you're invoking vf page from trigger, there might be chances of hitting heap size if number of records processed more or blob size is too big

Comment: You no longer need to use a Visualforce Page to create a PDF, you can do so directly by `Blob.toPdf(htmlContent)`.